# How do I display server side json data in Bootstrap model table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display json data in bootstrap model  table.
with ajax call I am puling the data from database and my controller returns the data in json format. 
I tried to populate the json data into my model table.
I dont know whats wrong. Can any body help me in this.

**My model table**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="popupTable" class="table-nonfluid" data-toggle="table" data-height="450"     width="450">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="countryCode">Country Code</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Number"> Number</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="errorMessage">Error Message</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="countryCode">Country Code</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="jobId"> job Id</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="organizationName">Organization Name</th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                  
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**I have a dataTabe like this**[image]

When I click on the number I should show me another table that is a popup. I have given the popup code on top.

This is the code when I click on numbers 121,2,72. it calls

```html
{
              
data : "numbers",
 render : function(data,type, row) {
 var failureRespons=data.split("|");
 if(failureRespons[1]=='0')
      {   
      return failureRespons[1];
   }
 else
 {
                              
 return '<a href="#" onclick="showFailureJobs('+failureRespons[0]+','+failureRespons[1]+')"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTable"><span class="text-primary">'+failureRespons[1]+'</span></a>'
                
 }               
}
}
```

**Ajax call**

```js
 function showFailureJobs(jobId,jobCount)
 {

   $.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : url bla bla,
   data : '',
   dataType : "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      crossDomain:true,
   success : function(data) { 
   
     $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() {
           
       $('#popupTable').bootstrapTable({
          columns: [{
                  field: 'countryCode',
                  title: 'Country Code'
              }, {
                  field: 'Number',
                  title: 'Number'
              }, {
                  field: 'errorMessage',
                  title: 'Error Message'
              }, {
                  field: 'jobId',
                  title: 'Job Id'
              },{
             
                  field: 'organizationName',
                  title: 'Organization Name'
              }, 

          ], 
          
      data:data
         
       });
     
       })   
       //Even I harcoded the data like this but I am not getting the data in table
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() {
              $('#popupTable').bootstrapTable({
              data: [
         {
           "countryCode" : "1",
           "Number" : "NL",
           "errorMessage" : "msg.",
           "jobId" : "1",
           "organizationName" : "us"
         },
         {
           "countryCode" : "2",
           "Number" : "NL",
           "errorMessage" : "msg",
           "jobId" : "10",
           "organizationName" : "us"
         }
              ]
          });
          })
      });
```

**My json Data format**

```html
countryCode   "NL"
Number        "4"
errorMessage   "msg"
jobId     "1"
organizationName  "us"
```

**update 1:** 
**html file content**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <title>
  Boostrap Modal Example
 </title>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() {
                $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                  
   data: [
    {
     "Number" : "1",
     "countryCode" : "NL",
     "errorMessage" : "msg.",
     "jobId" : "1",
     "organizationName" : "us"
   },
   {
     "Number" : "2",
     "countryCode" : "NL",
     "errorMessage" : "msg",
     "jobId" : "10",
     "organizationName" : "us"
   }
           ]
    });
    })
});


  </script>

  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTable">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<table id="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="jobId">Job ID</th>
     <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Number"> Number</th>
     <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="organizationName">Organization Name</th>
     <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="countryCode">Country Code</th>
     <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="errorMessage"> Error Message</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
    </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

</body>

  
</html>
```

Comment: `I tried to populate the json data into my model table. I dont know whats wrong`. what is your question actually ?

Comment: I am not able to populate json data in bootstrap model table

Comment: BootstrapTable works in table not div . `modalTable` id belongs to div , not table. you didn't post or write the code for opening modal and didn't provide the code which calls the function  `showFailureJobs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
New version - http://jsfiddle.net/1dwy3zx9/4/

---

You can load a datato table when modal shown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tempModalParameters = {
        jobId: null,
        jobCount: 0
    };

    $('.show-modal').click(function() {
        tempModalParameters.jobId = $(this).attr('data-jobId');
        tempModalParameters.jobCount = $(this).attr('data-jobCount');

        $('#modalTable').modal('show');
    });

    $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() {        
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: getFakeDataWithParameter(tempModalParameters.jobId,  tempModalParameters.jobCount)
        });

        $('#table').bootstrapTable('hideLoading');
    });


    function getFakeDataWithParameter(jobId, jobCount){   
        return [{
                "Number": "1",
                "countryCode": "NL",
                "errorMessage": "msg.",
                "jobId": "1",
                "organizationName": "us"
            }, {
                "Number": "2",
                "countryCode": "NL",
                "errorMessage": "msg",
                "jobId": "10",
                "organizationName": "us"
            }];

    }
});
```

You html should be like this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="show-modal" data-jobId="1" data-jobCount="2">1</a>
    <li><a href="#" class="show-modal" data-jobId="2" data-jobCount="2">2</a>
    <li><a href="#" class="show-modal" data-jobId="3" data-jobCount="2">3</a>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

<table id="table">
    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="jobId">Job ID</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Number"> Number</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-2" data-field="organizationName">Organization Name</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="countryCode">Country Code</th>
                            <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="errorMessage"> Error Message</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
</table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

And you need import a javascript for jQuery, Bootstrap and BootstrapTable (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I dont know Why My pop is not getting triggered ??

Comment: Firstly I think you must change $('#modalTable').bootstrapTable({ to $('#popupTable').bootstrapTable({

Comment: It's for you - working example - http://jsfiddle.net/1dwy3zx9/1/ . You must load your data when show modal -  $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() { // here load.  In example you have this code

Comment: Hi bro I tried multiple way but dint work. as mentioned I tried in same way. now I am able to triggered the popup table but data is not populating.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1dwy3zx9/1/ Here is working example. Loda data after show modal - $(document).ready(function() {     $('#modalTable').on('shown', function() { // here code to load data

Comment: Yes I saw That and I tried in same way but dint work. I am gona update the question please check

Comment: $('#modalTable').bootstrapTable({ change to $('#popupTable').bootstrapTable({

Comment: Every time I am getting `No matching records found` in the table

Comment: I have been trying your third comment js fiddle. in js fiddle its working, but when i try to copy the same content in and try to run then i get only modal along with table header not the data. i tried to do with simple html. what am i missing?any ways  I'll try your next solution. can you tell me what am i missing. I am updating the question with my html. please see and let me know where I am lacking.

Comment: Do you use a html and js or only js from js fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I think i found sth. In your code, you not imported a javascript for BootstrapTable - http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks bro ... It works. instead of putting  `$('#modalTable').on('shown', function() ` I used `$('#summaryModalTable').on('shown.bs.modal',function()`

Comment: Ok great :) If my answer was helpful and you could, please vote up :)